# adding border to list item selection

Tags: listview, sencha-touch-2, border, listitem

```
       xtype:'list',
     // disableSelection: true,  
      scrollToTopOnRefresh: false,
      style:'background:red',
      store: 'PchatStore',
      selectedCls:'chatmsg',
```

[image: image border is not applied to top]

```
.chatmsg{

      border-bottom : 7px solid yellow;  

       border-left : 7px solid yellow;  

        border-right : 7px solid yellow; 

        border-top : 7px solid yellow;
```

}

the `border`is not applied on top of the `list`on selecting a `list`item

Answer (score 0):

try only..

```
border: 7px solid yellow;
```